# Add multiple records using forr loop in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing a selenium test script for my student management system. I have a situation where I need to enter values and click the same button 15 times. So, I used a for loops for the scenario.

Here is the screen I need to test.

[image: mark]

So, **I need to add two values to mark range text boxes and select grade from the drop down list and click add button**. I need to do this scenario for 15 times.

Here are the values I need to enter

[image: data]

Here is the drop down list.

[image: grades]

I tried following scenario for this.

```
for(int x=95; x<=11; x=x-6){

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='number']")).sendKeys(""+x);

            for(int y=100; y<=16; y=y-6){

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='number'])[2]")).sendKeys(""+y);

                for(int z=1; z<=15; z++){

                    Select mark2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='gradeSelector']")));
                    mark2.selectByValue(""+z);
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add']")).click();
                }
            }
        }
```

but, nothing happens.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
    int x=95, y=100;
    for(int z=1; z <=15; z++){

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='number']")).sendKeys(""+x);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='number'])[2]")).sendKeys(""+y);
        Select mark2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='gradeSelector']")));
        //mark2.selectByValue(""+z);
        mark2.selectByIndex(z);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add']")).click();

        x=x-6;
        y=y-6;
    }
```

Comment: Not working. 95 and 100 types in the two text fields and test fails. :)

Comment: Could please share the exception trace for failure?

Comment: In this particular scenario, you can also use 'selectByIndex' method instead of 'selectByValue', as shown in the modified code above. Please try the modified code and let me know whether the code works as per your expectation.

Comment: locators are working. I think my for loop is wrong somehow. :(

Comment: Above code should work, as I have checked the values for x, y and z counter variables during each iteration and if we do not have any issues with locator, then expected data should be entered in the required fields. Could you please share the output and error (if any), after adding System.out.println statements for x, y and z variables in above loop?

Answer (score 1):

It's just the for loop logic is incorrect - the `x<=11` condition never evaluates to true, replace:

```
for(int x=95; x<=11; x=x-6) {
```

with:

```
for(int x=95; x>=11; x=x-6) {
```

Comment: I think now my inner loop is wrong some way. It is just printing `958983777165595347413529231711` in the first text box